# Create raw transaction what txid

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-id, createrawtransaction

I want to check for every transaction if there is enough balance to pay it(including fee). I found this question:
[Is there a way to know the Bitcoin Network transaction fee BEFORE actually submitting the transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44152/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-bitcoin-network-transaction-fee-before-actually-submi/44157)

But what do I have to use as the TXID by createrawtransaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the console do `listunspent`
that will show you all the UTXO in your wallet including the txids.
You can type `help` to get a list of commands,
then `help <command>` to get details about each command